# What works of Kierkegaard have yet to be translated into English?

Tags: translation, kierkegaard

I have recently begun reading *The Sickness Unto Death*, and I find myself falling in love with Kierkegaard's uniquely multifaceted indirect communication. I have found myself wondering how much of his work is still inaccessible to me as someone who only knows English. Does anybody know where I can find a complete list of his writings both translated and untranslated, and then short of this, which of Kierkegaard's writings have yet to be translated into English and published?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of Kierkegaard's published works have been translated into English and are available in several different translations luckily!

I believe most or all of Kierkegaard's unpublished work - in the form of journals and loose papers - have also been translated into English, the most recent translation being [Kierkegaard's Journals and Notebooks](https://press.princeton.edu/series/kierkegaards-journals-and-notebooks), which just published the last volume in its series this year.

Other notable recent translations:

- [2009 translation of Repetition and Philosophical Crumbs](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6704723-repetition-and-philosophical-crumbs) (Oxford World's Classics).  This one at least more correctly translates as "crumbs" instead of the more ambiguous "fragments", which is the traditional and less accurate translation.
- [2018 translation of The Lily of the Field and the Bird of the Air: Three Godly Discourses](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/26597402-the-lily-of-the-field-and-the-bird-of-the-air)
- [2021 translation of Fear and Trembling](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/55298323-fear-and-trembling)

[Wikipedia has a great list of these works](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%B8ren_Kierkegaard_bibliography) for those curious.

Comment: I just realized I never said thanks for answering my question. Thanks so much! I really appreciate it.